# Unable to copy a custom keyboard layout to "Library/Keyboard\ Layouts"

Tags: keyboard

I attempted to copy a custom keyboard layout [as I have done on many other macbooks in the past]:

```
$sudo cp usd2.keylayout "/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts"
```

No errors happened. But then why is it not there?

```
$ls -lrta /Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    64 Dec  2 06:37 .
drwxr-xr-x  69 root  wheel  2208 Jan 16 08:52 ..
```

I am on `macOS Ventura`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quoting issue: `sudo cp usd2.keylayout "/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts"` copied your layout into a file called `Keyboard\ Layouts` within `/Library`.

To fix, run

```sh
sudo rm "/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts"
sudo cp sd2.keylayout "/Library/Keyboard Layouts"
```

PS: You can also run `sudo mv "/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts" "/Library/Keyboard Layouts"/sd2.keylayout` to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yea, in recent versions of `macOS` the proper place is under the user's home directory ie

```
cp usd2.keylayout "~/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts"
```

Comment: You should be able to put it in either place.

Comment: Are you sure this command does what you expect it to do?

Comment: @nohillside  Not sure what you mean - this did work .. ?

Comment: Oh i saw your answer now.  The command shown here did work, not sure why quoting works in this case and not in the original question

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: i'm using `bash`